# boost::variant as friend class

Tags: c++, boost, c++98, boost-variant

For a type `Foo`, which I want to use in a `boost::variant`, I wanted to set the default constructor to `private`, since it only should be allowed to be called by `boost::variant`.

Sadly I could not yet figure out the declaration magic of `boost::variant` and simply declaring

```
struct Foo {
private:
  Foo();
  template <class T1, class T2>
  friend class boost::variant<T1, T2>;
};
```

did not compile either. Is there any way to do this or do I need to keep `Foo()` `public`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When variadic templates are available, you would have to use `template <BOOST_VARIANT_ENUM_PARAMS(class T)> friend class boost::variant;` otherwise you get an error: ‘BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1_BOOST_VARIANT_LIMIT_TYPES’ has not been declared.

Here's a minimal  <kbd>[working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a16a5aa30c06c237)</kbd>:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/enum_params.hpp>

struct Foo {
public:
    Foo(int){};
private:
    Foo();
    template <BOOST_VARIANT_ENUM_PARAMS(class T)> friend class boost::variant;
    int i;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo(10);
    boost::variant<Foo> test=foo;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[This answer addresses C++98/03 only; for modern code, see below]

The number of template parameters of `boost::variant` is given by [`BOOST_VARIANT_LIMIT_TYPES`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/BOOST_VARIANT_LIMIT_TYPES.html). You could use it by harnessing [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html):

```
#include "boost/preprocessor/repetition/enum_params.hpp"

struct Foo {
private:
  Foo();

  template <BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(BOOST_VARIANT_LIMIT_TYPES, class T)>
  friend class boost::variant;
};
```

`boost::variant` is declared as a class template with `BOOST_VARIANT_LIMIT_TYPES` template parameters, so you must refer to it as such. This is the job for `BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(a, b)`, which expands into a list of `a` comma-delimited items, each of which is `b` with a unique number appended. For example,

```
BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(5, class T)
```

will expand to:

```
class T0, class T1, class T2, class T3, class T4
```

---

Note that the above applies within the scope of the question, that is, limited to C++98/03. Since C++11, variadic templates exist and when these are available to Boost, `BOOST_VARIANT_LIMIT_TYPES` is not defined and the above code does not work. Boost offers an alternative which works both with and without variadics; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58999393/1782465) for details.

Comment: I think this there's no guarantee that the instantiating code is `boost::variant` itself, rather than one of its helper classes. But I haven't looked at implementation. Maybe it's part of the documented interface.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Good point. I answered the question of "how to befriend `boost::variant`," not the broader "how to use a private ctor with `boost::variant`." I will leave it to the OP to figure out whether it works for them or not; I'm willing to be outcompeted by a better answer, and/or withdraw mine in case it's found to be insufficient.

Comment: I checked that `boost::variant` does the instantiation, before :). That said, the proposal does at least churn out a syntax error on VS2010 in identifier `BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1_class`.

Comment: @abergmeier Whoops, I swapped the argument order accidentally. Corrected.

Comment: I had to use `template <BOOST_VARIANT_ENUM_PARAMS(class T)> friend class boost::variant;` instead. Otherwise I had an error about ‘BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1_BOOST_VARIANT_LIMIT_TYPES’ has not been declared

Comment: @cosurgi Yes, this apparently happens when variadic templates are available to Boost (which was not the case for the original question/answer). I could edit it into my answer, but I think it would be better if you posted it as a new answer, which will be universal. I will then edit mine to add a disclaimer "this is a manual pre-viariadics solution".